# Unique filter on a specific column within a view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a SQL view that looks like this:

| Client Group | Assistant Manager | Client | Invoice ID | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCD | John | EFGH | I00050 | 1/12/2022 | 150 |
| ABCD | John | EFGH | I00050 | 1/12/2022 | 150 |
| ABCD | John | EFGH | 100051 | 1/12/2022 | 150 |

I would like only the Invoice ID column to show unique values:

So ideally, the result should look like this:

| Client Group | Assistant Manager | Client | Invoice ID | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCD | John | EFGH | I00050 | 1/12/2022 | 150 |
| ABCD | John | EFGH | I00051 | 1/12/2022 | 150 |

The code that I've used is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT        ClientGroups.Name,
                       CustomFieldValues.CustomValue,
                       Invoices.Client,
                       Invoices.InvoiceId,
                       Invoices.Date,
                       Invoices.Amount
FROM                   Invoices INNER JOIN
                       ClientGroups ON ClientGroups.ClientId = Invoices.ClientId INNER JOIN
                       CustomFieldValues ON CustomFieldValues.EntityId = Invoices.ClientId
WHERE                 (Invoices.Date > '2021-06-30') AND (CustomFieldValues.CustomField = 'Client Manager- assistant')
```

But the above does not get rid of the duplicate invoice id's from the invoice ID column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you will need to group by invoice ID, and get MAX() of every column using `group by` and `max()` :

```
SELECT  MAX(ClientGroups.Name) as 'Client Group',
        MAX(CustomFieldValues.CustomValue) as 'Assistant Manager',
        MAX(Invoices.Client) as 'Client',
        Invoices.InvoiceId as 'Invoice Id',
        MAX(Invoices.Date) as 'Date',
        MAX(Invoices.Amount) as 'Amount'
FROM  Invoices 
INNER JOIN
     ClientGroups ON ClientGroups.ClientId = Invoices.ClientId 
INNER JOIN
    CustomFieldValues ON CustomFieldValues.EntityId = Invoices.ClientId
WHERE  (Invoices.Date > '2021-06-30') 
        AND (CustomFieldValues.CustomField = 'Client Manager- assistant')
GROUP BY Invoices.InvoiceId
```

Comment: Thank you very much and your code worked! Except now, none of the columns have any names. Are you able to advise how to add column names to the columns? I intend on pulling this information into PowerBI and work in direct querry mode so no column names will be an issue.

Comment: Glad to hear, you can add names as alias using `AS`, Can you check my edit

Answer (score 0):

Check the string values in 'Invoice ID' column. Your query should work if the values are the same. Check if I00050 in both two separate rows begins with capital 'i' and not with capital 'i' or '1' in one row and 'el' in the other.